# Hyphens and minuses are MIA.

Tags: packages, hyperref, hyphenation

I am experiencing a strange bug involving the omission of hyphens in the .dvi file.

```
% This is a sample LaTeX input file.  (Version of 12 August 2004.) % % A '%' character causes TeX to ignore all remaining text on the line, % and is used for comments like this one.

\documentclass{article}      % Specifies the document class

                             % The preamble begins here. \usepackage{hyperref}

\title{ Chapter 0, A Quick Description of the Workings of a Computer }
% Declares the document's title.
\author{John M. Morrison}      % Declares the author's name.
%\date{\today}      % Deleting this command produces today's date.

\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\newenvironment{code}{\begin{quote}\obeylines\tt\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}{\end{quote}}
\newenvironment{ul}{\begin{itemize}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt} }{\end{itemize}}
\newenvironment{ol}{\begin{enumerate}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}{\end{enumerate}}
\setcounter{section}{-1}
\begin{document}             % End of preamble and beginning of text.

\maketitle                   % Produces the title.
\tableofcontents
\input c0core.tex


\end{document}               % End of document.
```

This code in the document c0core.tex

```
\section{Integers and Computers}
Every operating system has a word size; machines today are 32 or 64 bit
machines. What does this mean? The most basic unit of memory in a computer is
an integer, or whole number. There are two types of integer, signed integers
and unsigned integers. Unsigned integers are always non-negative. Unsigned
integers are used to supply memory addresses for your computer’s RAM. Signed
integers (having a + or - sign) are often used in arithmetic. When the computer
puts them to the screen or a file, you see a sign for the integer. When the
computer manipulates them behind the scenes, it actually stores them as
unsigned integers using a very clever scheme. We will discuss this scheme
shortly, but we will begin by looking at unsigned integers.

If you have a 32 bit machine, integers have 32 bits; likewise, if you have a 64
bit machine, integers have 64 bits. A 32 bit unsigned integer can store numbers
from 0 to $2^{32}$ − 1. This number represents the 4 gig limit for usable RAM
on 32 bit machines. A 64 bit unsigned integer can store numbers from 0 to
$2^{64} − 1$; this can support memory up to 18 exabytes. Since today’s machines
are coming with 4 or more gigs of RAM, going to the 64 bit system is necessary.
A 32 bit unsigned integer can be represented with 8 hex digits; a 64 bit
integer requires 16 hex digits. Unsigned integers are just plain–vanilla binary
numbers.
```

The - signs and hyphens fail to appear in this segment of code.  Is there a bug or conflict in the packages?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` might "solve" the problem, but Gonzalo's solution is better since it makes the hypens _hyphens_ that TeX can then deal with as hyphens...

Comment: @Seamus: in this case, loading `inputenc` with the `utf8` option will produce compilation errors due to the "strange" character `−` not being recognized.

Comment: @Gonzalo is the minus not a recognised utf8 character? I thought it was...

Comment: @Seamus: the keyboard minus sign is recognized, but the sign used by ncmathsadist in some places is different.

Comment: @Seamus: I guess with Lua/XeTeX and a proper font it should work. Sill, minuses should be set in math mode for spacing and consistent font use (as the math font might differ from the main font). Dashes (– and —) can of course be used with these systems (though I usually avoid them because they all look the same in monospace fonts in the editor).

Comment: Something weird happened when I tarred and transferred the file.  Apostrophes and hyphens got transmogrified into non-ASCII monstrosities.  I opened this with Texshop and it is seeing the problem. I did not see the problem in vi, which happily made the monstrosities masquerade as their ASCII brethrn. Ugh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character that you are using as minus sign is `−` which is not recognized; use the keyboard character `-` instead. Here's the modified version of the text (I also used the plus and minus signs consistently in math mode):

```
\section{Integers and Computers}
Every operating system has a word size; machines today are 32 or 64 bit
machines. What does this mean? The most basic unit of memory in a computer is
an integer, or whole number. There are two types of integer, signed integers
and unsigned integers. Unsigned integers are always non-negative. Unsigned
integers are used to supply memory addresses for your computer's RAM. Signed
integers (having a $+$ or $-$ sign) are often used in arithmetic. When the computer
puts them to the screen or a file, you see a sign for the integer. When the
computer manipulates them behind the scenes, it actually stores them as
unsigned integers using a very clever scheme. We will discuss this scheme
shortly, but we will begin by looking at unsigned integers.

If you have a 32 bit machine, integers have 32 bits; likewise, if you have a 64
bit machine, integers have 64 bits. A 32 bit unsigned integer can store numbers
from 0 to $2^{32} - 1$. This number represents the 4 gig limit for usable RAM
on 32 bit machines. A 64 bit unsigned integer can store numbers from 0 to
$2^{64} - 1$; this can support memory up to 18 exabytes. Since today’s machines
are coming with 4 or more gigs of RAM, going to the 64 bit system is necessary.
A 32 bit unsigned integer can be represented with 8 hex digits; a 64 bit
integer requires 16 hex digits. Unsigned integers are just plain–vanilla binary
numbers.
```

Comment: It is the keyboard - character.  I enclosed the + and - in $s but I still have missing hyphens.

Comment: @ncmathsadist: no, it is not. You can see the minus sign from the keyboard in your text in the sentence "(having a + or - sign)"; but in "$2^{64} − 1$" the sign used is clearly different.

Comment: @ncmath: As you can [check here](http://unicodelookup.com), sometimes you have a Unicode minus sign instead of a Unicode/ASCII hyphen in your text.

Comment: I just transfered this file from a linux machine to a mac.  I tarred it on the linux box, brought it across and untarred  it on the mac.  Could that be a culprit?

Comment: I just did an od -bc on the entire document and all -s come up as 055 which is the correct ASCII octal code for -.  It could be triggered by some other TeX error earlier int the document, but the log output does not flag anything other than the occasional overfull box.

Comment: This thing is also eating apostrophes.

Comment: @ncmathsadist: yes, apostrophes in your text are also wrong (I forgot to mention that in my answer). If you look at the code in my answer and compare it with the text in your question, you'll see that I changed the apostrophe in  "computer's" to the standard one, but I forgot to do so with the apostrophe in "today’s". You'll have to do a search and replace for the pairs "−", "-", and "’", "'".

Comment: Your answer got me on the right path to extirpating this problem.  Thank you.  I think there is some funny business with tar going on here but I am not sure.

Comment: @ncm: I think is unlikely that `tar` is the culprit, as it is specifically designed not to change anything in the files. I'd rather suspect some editor to try too hard to be helpful.

Comment: This problem did not emerge until the file was transferred.